# Maven shade plugin overlapping classes vs. dependency plugin omitted for conflict

Tags: maven, dependencies

I'm using the Maven shade plugin, and I get output like the following from `mvn package`:

```
[WARNING] kryo-4.0.0.jar, kryo-2.21.jar define 91 overlapping classes:
```

followed by:

```
[WARNING] maven-shade-plugin has detected that some class files are
[WARNING] present in two or more JARs.
[WARNING] single version of the class is copied to the uber jar.
[WARNING] Usually this is not harmful and you can skip these warnings,
[WARNING] otherwise try to manually exclude artifacts based on
[WARNING] mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true and the above output.
```

On the other hand, there are many other jars that I would expect to get such warnings for, but I don't. In particular, if I do `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`, I get a lot of output like:

```
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.5)
```

My question is, why do some cases of duplicate classes result only in the "overlapping classes" warnings, while other cases result only in the "omitted for conflict" information messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The groupId of kryo changed from version 2.x to 3.x. This means that technically, kryo 4.0.0 and kryo 2.21 are different artifacts for Maven. No dependency mediation occurs, they are just put both on the classpath. This is why the shade plugin complains.

Comment: Thanks. That explanation also correctly accounts for several other similarly-named jars that I didn't list, which also have overlapping classes: reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar, reflectasm-1.11.3.jar; grapht-core-0.9.3.jar, jgrapht-core-1.0.0.jar; minlog-1.3.0.jar, minlog-1.2.jar.